# Jcarousel initialization in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jcarousel

I try to implement jcarousel gallery in this dummy article http://mybistrotableandchairs.com/hghg/

Setup feels ok (look at page source), but jcarousel is not initialized.

What should i change in the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya see **demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/Znztg/

Hope this helps! and works for multiple carousal for less code. CHeers

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ for more read if you keen!

I recently replied to the post with working solution; hence reusing my code :))   [Multiple instances of this carousel on a single page - can't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053780/multiple-instances-of-this-carousel-on-a-single-page-cant-get-it-to-work/10053975#10053975)

I also had a look into your implementation I think the jsfiddle and code will help you to get it sorted rest flick me message anytime,have a good one man!

**Library**

```
<!--

      jCarousel library
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <!--
      jCarousel skin stylesheets
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/ie7/skin.css" />
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the first and second carousel by class selector.
    // Note that they use both the same configuration options (none in this case).
    $('.first-and-second-carousel').jcarousel();

    // If you want to use a caoursel with different configuration options,
    // you have to initialise it seperately.
    // We do it by an id selector here.
    $('#third-carousel').jcarousel();
    // alert('foo');
});
```

**HTML**

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>jCarousel</h1>
  <h2>Riding carousels with jQuery</h2>

  <h3>Multiple carousels on one page</h3>
  <p>
    This example shows how to use multiple carousels on one page with different
        skins and configurations.
  </p>

  <ul id="first-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

  <hr size="1"/>

  <ul id="second-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel jcarousel-skin-ie7">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

  <hr size="1"/>

  <ul id="third-carousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</body>​
```

Comment: the problem was with scripts paths, now it seems ok.

Comment: perfect! yep usually a syntax error or script path is a culprit! :)